# VS Code incorrectly assumes the variable's type is it's identifier when the type is an array in the C programming language

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I am using VS Code to practice writing C code and I found a really annoying thing about it's syntax highlighting which even Discord's markdown, Vim and CLion get right.

In a function declaration like

```c
double atof2(const char[]); // I know arrays shouldn't be function inputs
```

VS Code assumes that `char` is the name of the parameter (which doesn't have a name yet since this is just a declaration) and highlights it with light blue instead of dark blue as shown in [image: this] image. It should be dark blue like all keywords but it isn't. Is there a way to fix this or do I just need to open an issue?

Since other people have been able to reproduce it (here and on Discord) here's the link to the issue I opened on Github: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/138695

Comment: Can't reproduce. Keep in mind, C++ and C are two different languages. Make sure you have selected the right language mode in VS Code. Though the issue might be an extension that screws with the syntax highlighting.

Comment: Try this: `int bitlength(unsigned int);`. Disable all extensions. int should be highlighted with light blue instead of the color for keywords which is dark blue.
@sbecker

Comment: You are right. I got confused. I can in fact reproduce the issue with the language mode C. Though with language mode C++, it seems to work fine for me. In C++, the type is colored dark blue, as it should.

Comment: Opened an issue on Github. Here's the link: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/138695